Use case for integrating Chocolatey with SCCM
System Center Configuration Manager seems to have the features for publishing packaged applications so that employees of an enterprise can install applications from a central repository using the Software Center application installed on Windows. I see articles on the internet that state that Chocolatey has an integration with SCCM but do not explicitly state the precise use case wherein this integration is required. Can anyone suggest why one might need Chocolatey to work with SCCM?

NOTE
I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask. In fact, I'm pretty sure this will be closed as not a developer-type of question. Server Fault feels like a better place for questions like this.
Integrating Chocolatey into SCCM
So the integration is in SCCM using Chocolatey behind the scenes and there are a few reasons why this is good:

Source Control Benefits - Chocolatey packaging can be put into source
control, so you can see what changed as you deploy new versions of
packages.
Testing - Chocolatey packages are essentially deployments of
applications (install/upgrade). That means you can independently
test those deployments in different automated ways before you go to
put it into SCCM.
Package Anything - Chocolatey packages can just be files,
configuration, zip apps, etc. You can even just run a PowerShell
script. That means when it is put with SCCM, it can allow SCCM to
track more things and not mostly just apps that come with
installers. Even your own LOB apps.
Report All Software - C4B adds the ability to track non-installers
in Programs and Features, so you can easily track all software
placed on a computer and not just installers.
Chocolatey Packages Are Independent - Chocolatey packages are
independent building blocks, so they can be deployed with or without
SCCM. Which is good when you have some areas like servers where you
may be using a configuration manager (like Ansible or PowerShell
DSC) - you get the benefit of a build once, use every type of
packaging.

There are other benefits, but these are just a few reasons. If you bring your question to Server Fault, that would be a better place to ask. And we could get into the specifics of what that actually looks like.
